# How do I call removeView() on child's parent?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a simple android `alertdialog` box. This is my code:

```
LinearLayout diagLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
diagLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         TextView text = new TextView(getContext());
         if(text.getParent()!=null)
             ((ViewGroup)text.getParent()).removeView(text);

         text.setText("Hello");
         diagLayout.addView(text);

         builder.setView(diagLayout);

         builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  dialogInterface.dismiss();
              }
         });

         AlertDialog ad=builder.create();
         ad.show();  //this is where the error shows
   }
});
```

When I click the `btn`, the dialog shows. Then when I press the `Cancel` button and then again press the `btn`, my app crashes and the following error shows up in my console:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
> parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

I have no idea why this error is occurring and how to fix this. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the **Linearlayout** locally, solved the issue:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
         LinearLayout diagLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
         diagLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         TextView text = new TextView(getContext());

         text.setText("Hello");
         diagLayout.addView(text);

         builder.setView(diagLayout);

         builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                  dialogInterface.dismiss();
              }
         });

         AlertDialog ad=builder.create();
         ad.show();
   }
});
```